# How do I store/save an ordered list of user inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I've got a somehow noob question here. What is the easiest/ideal/most appropriate form element or way of allowing a user to enter multiple items (text inputs) in a specific order? The list ought to be stored in an array in the same order as the entered one.

Specifically, I'd like for the resulting array to something like the following:

```
const directions = [
 'Step 1: Firstly, do something',
 'Step 2: Then do something',
 'Step 3: Then do something',
 'Step 4: Then do something',
 'Step 5: Finally, do something'
]
```

Just to be clear, I know I can use the obvious multiple text inputs or even a textarea but I feel like there is a better way. As already mentioned, the goal is to end up with an ordered/sorted list of items stored as an array.

I'm not sure if I need to include code snippets of what I currently have, though I've included the relevant parts. I'm working with Vue.js 2 but I've encountered the same issue with React and even vanilla JS.

**Template part**

```
<template>
    <div class="new-recipe">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s6 offset-s3">
                <form @submit.prevent="addRecipe">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12">
                            <h3>Add Recipe</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input id="dish_name" type="text" class="validate" v-model="dish_name">
                            <label for="dish_name">Dish Name</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <select multiple v-model="dish_type">
                              <option value="" disabled selected>Select dish type</option>
                              <template v-for="dish in dish_types">
                                <option 
                                    :value="dish.type" 
                                    :key="dish.type"
                                >
                                {{ dish.type }}
                                </option>
                              </template>
                            </select>
                          <label>Dish Type</label>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s6">
                            <input id="image" type="text" class="validate" v-model="image">
                            <label for="image">Image Link</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s6">
                            <input id="video" type="text" class="validate" v-model="video">
                            <label for="video">Video Link</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s3">
                            <select v-model="rating">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Rating</option>
                                <template v-for="rating in 5">
                                    <option :value="rating" :key="rating">{{ rating }} star(s)</option>
                                </template>
                            </select>
                            <label>Select Rating</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s3">
                            <input id="servings" type="text" class="validate" v-model="servings">
                            <label for="servings">Servings</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s3">
                            <input id="prep_time" type="text" class="validate" v-model="prep_time">
                            <label for="prep_time">Prep. Time (in min)</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s3">
                            <select v-model="difficulty">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Difficulty</option>
                                <option value="Easy">Easy</option>
                                <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                                <option value="Hard">Hard</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Select Difficulty</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <textarea 
                                id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" 
                                v-model="ingredients">
                            </textarea>
                        <label for="textarea1">Ingredients</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <textarea 
                                id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" 
                                v-model="directions">
                            </textarea>
                        <label for="textarea1">Directions</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12">
                            <button class="btn">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Script Part**

```
<script>
    /* eslint-disable */
    import { dish_types } from '../../testData';

    export default {
        name: 'newrecipe',
        data() {
            return {
                dish_name: null,
                dish_types,
                dish_type: [],
                image: null,
                video: null,
                servings: null,
                prep_time: null,
                rating: null,
                difficulty: null,
                ingredients: [],
                directions: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            navigateTo(tab) {
                this.$router.push(tab)
            },
            clear() {
            this.$refs.form.reset()
          },
          addRecipe() {
            const recipe = {};

            recipe.dish_name = this.dish_name;
                recipe.dish_type = this.dish_type;
                recipe.image = this.image;
                recipe.video = this.video;
                recipe.servings = this.servings;
                recipe.prep_time = this.prep_time;
                recipe.rating = this.rating;
                recipe.difficulty = this.difficulty;
                recipe.ingredients = this.ingredients;
                recipe.directions = this.directions;

            console.log(recipe);
            this.$store.dispatch('saveRecipe', recipe)
                this.$router.push('/recipes')
            this.clear();
          }
        }
    };
</script>
```